# Is a valid markup to use several data parameters on div with same values?

Tags: html

I have something like:

```
<div id="div1" data-org="300">Some info</div>
<div id="div2" data-org="300">Some info</div>
<div id="div3" data-org="300">Some info</div>
```

I know you cant repeat *ids* with the same value, but you can repeat the values (and names) of other custom parameters? like the *data-org*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

ID is the only attribute that must have unique values.

Some other attributes have different restrictions (see the spec for details), but `data-*` attributes have no restrictions whatsoever.